# Compositeness test using $S_i=6S_{i-1}-11S_{i-2}+6S_{i-3}$ recurrence relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

Can you prove or disprove the following claim:

> Let $S_i=6S_{i-1}-11S_{i-2}+6S_{i-3}$ with $S_0=0$ , $S_1=1$ , $S_2=1$ . Let $n$ be a natural number greater than $3$, then:
>   $$\text{If } n \text{ is a prime number then } S_{n-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1jc0KwjAQhO99Cu0pabaQVPSy7smz0PYNrFYM5KdkKyLiu5scvAzMzDdMoD1Wab4KDz0MMEr6sCaNbMggd1kc7fD1sG4W7kgemPqGOzU0bNTYcCY1sSk8d2XA6JSSmOb1mYJgid_K3sU53kR5Ca2BA7Qmq4QgiTQsyYZV1H2K02Vy7032ft7W8l-col8i27VkEn-hwDQy&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). I have verified this claim for all $n$ up to $100000$ .

I was searching for counterexample using the following PARI/GP code:

```
rec(m,P,Q,R)={s0=0;s1=1;s2=1;l=3;while(l<=m,s=P*s2+Q*s1+R*s0;s0=s1;s1=s2;s2=s;l++);return(s);}
RPT(n1,n2)={forprime(n=n1,n2,if(Mod(rec(n-1,6,-11,6),n)!=0,print(n);break))}
```

Comment: Can you solve the recursion, to get a formula for $S_n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the roots of
$$x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6 = 0$$
are $1, 2, 3$.

Thus, the general term can be written as
$$S_n = A\cdot1^n + B\cdot2^n + C\cdot3^n$$
for some constants $A, B, C$.

(See [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/) for details.)

---

Using $S_0, S_1, S_2$, we can determine $(A, B, C)$. It turns out to be $(-2, 3, -1)$. That is,
$$S_n = -2 + 3\cdot2^n - 3^n.$$

---

Now, since $n$ is a prime number coprime to $2$ and $3$, we have
$$2^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$$
and 
$$3^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n.$$
This follows from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

In this case, we have
$$S_{n-1} \equiv -2 + 3 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod n,$$
as desired.

---

**EDIT:** Additional observation! We didn't even have to calculate $(A, B, C).$
Once we know that $S_n = A + B\cdot2^n + C\cdot3^n$, Fermat's little theorem would directly give us
$$S_{n-1} \equiv A + B +C \equiv S_0 \pmod n.$$
We already have that $S_0 = 0 \equiv 0\pmod n$ and thus, we would be done.